Does anyone know hwo to parse through dexscreeener page for pair address?
Below is the current function
async function extractLiquidityPool(tokenUrl) {
    try {
        if (!tokenUrl.startsWith("http")) {
            console.error(`Invalid URL: ${tokenUrl}`);
            return null;
        }
        const response = await axios.get(tokenUrl);
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        // Locate the liquidity pool address based on the DOM structure
        const liquidityPoolAddress = $("span.chakra-text.custom-72pvq").text(); // Adjust this selector
        if (liquidityPoolAddress && liquidityPoolAddress.length >= 32) {
            console.log(`Extracted Liquidity Pool Address: ${liquidityPoolAddress}`);
            return liquidityPoolAddress.trim();
        }
        console.error("Liquidity pool address not found in HTML.");
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching or parsing Dexscreener page:", error.message);
        return null;
    }
}

